# NDSolve error message: "The function value {0,0,0}==0 is not True or False..."

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

When I run `NDSlve` with the following equation, it returns the right result but also prints the error messages, that I don't understand:

INPUT:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
NDSolve[{r[0]=={0,0,0},Derivative[1][r][0]=={232.6505345510563`,0.`,195.21697773498838`},r''[t]=={2 {-0.000050436176034386066`,0.`,0.00005238977971251114`}\[Cross]Derivative[1][r][t]-0.000030107939363395976` \[Sqrt](Abs[-3.746824092050303`+Derivative[1][r][t]]^2+Abs[0.` +Derivative[1][r][t]]^2+Abs[0.9193251425526601` +Derivative[1][r][t]]^2) (-3.746824092050303`+Derivative[1][r][t]),2 {-0.000050436176034386066`,0.`,0.00005238977971251114`}\[Cross]Derivative[1][r][t]-0.000030107939363395976` \[Sqrt](Abs[-3.746824092050303`+Derivative[1][r][t]]^2+Abs[0.` +Derivative[1][r][t]]^2+Abs[0.9193251425526601` +Derivative[1][r][t]]^2) (0.9193251425526601` +Derivative[1][r][t]),-9.806`+2 {-0.000050436176034386066`,0.`,0.00005238977971251114`}\[Cross]Derivative[1][r][t]-0.000030107939363395976` \[Sqrt](Abs[-3.746824092050303`+Derivative[1][r][t]]^2+Abs[0.` +Derivative[1][r][t]]^2+Abs[0.9193251425526601` +Derivative[1][r][t]]^2) (0.` +Derivative[1][r][t])}},r[t],{t,0,60}]
```

This equation didn't copy correctly to stack exchange, so this is a picture of it:
[image]

ERROR MESSAGES:
[image]
[image]

I have no idea how it gets `{0,0,0}==0`.

Comment: ``2 {-0.000050436176034386066`, 0.`, 
   0.00005238977971251114`}\[Cross]Derivative[1][r][t]`` evaluates to a matrix after the value of `r'[t]` is substituted...

Comment: Is ``Abs[0.` + Derivative[1][r][t]]`` a vector or do you mean `Norm[..]`? (r'[t] is a vector. `Abs[{x,y,z}]` is the same as `{Abs[x], Abs[y], Abs[z]}`.

Comment: I think you need to give a mathematical (TeX) description of what you're trying to do. I get the feeling that the ODE has been constructed incorrectly.

Comment: The context is quite simple. it is just balistic trajectury with random (inside a circle) horizontal wind, a quadratic air drag and coriolis force.  Here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18lErO5Hvkw0HnLzcwgRyAQ28cHz-WbRe?usp=sharing  is the original notebook (Flat earth version). Surprizingly the more general round earth version (other notebook) does not print those errors.

Comment: Note "\[Cross]" (displayed as: x" is an abbreviation for the cross product. And "vector1 vector2" multiplies the element wise. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Yes, it is meant as a cross product.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that the derivation of `r''[t]` is messed up. Note what `{1, 2, 3} + r'[t]` evaluates to. It's tricky to combine vectors with separate components like `{x, y, z}` from symbols that represent vectors like `r[t]` and `r'[t]`. The fix to your problem has little to do with what is posted above. It comes from how the above was derived.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed, that the equation above is not the same as the original (in the notebook, I sent.). I just copied the equation above from error message, but it looks like it has done some simplification for norm, which instead of components pluged in vector. However the solution (as ploted in nb) looks correct (similar to one, i got directly from euler alg.) Maybe NDSolve makes error message in the first step and it in later steps figures out, that r is a vector, and then does everything ok (that' s just a gues). Anyway, I will edit the question tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a reverse-engineered code from un-`Thread`-ing the constant-vector sums and putting the constant vectors in `NumericQ`-protected constant functions:

```
Clear[a, b, c, r, t];
a[t_?NumericQ] := {-0.000050436176034386066`, 0.`, 
   0.00005238977971251114`};
b[t_?NumericQ] := {-3.746824092050303`, 0.9193251425526601`, 0.};
rsol = NDSolve[{
    r[0] == {0, 0, 0},
    r'[0] == {232.6505345510563`, 0.`, 195.21697773498838`}, 
    r''[t] == 2 a[t] \[Cross] r'[t] - 
       0.000030107939363395976` Norm[b[t] + r'[t]] (b[t] + r'[t])},
   r, {t, 0, 60000}];

Graphics3D[{
  ColorData[97][1], AbsoluteThickness[1.6],
  Line[r@"ValuesOnGrid" /. First@rsol]
  }, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works. There is also another constant with the r'', but if i define it the same way: g[t_?NumericQ] := {0, 0, -9.81}; it works correctly.